# Wrapping text in span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a chrome extension that will change the color of certain words on the screen. I am having trouble finding the text which meets my needs and then accurately wrapping it in a span. Oftentimes the same word in html is replaced in other locations in the page, rendering links and styles useless.

My example code follows:

```
var reArray = ['number', 'numbers'];
var re = new RegExp('\\b('+reArray.join('|')+')\\b', 'gi');
$('p, span').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(re, '<span class="gold">$1</span>'));
});
```

Comment: suggest you use a plugin that has already been well tested for doing this

Comment: This code seems like it's working to me: http://jsfiddle.net/zyereb3k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the following regex works when replacing in the body.

```
(>[^<]*?)\\b(words|you|want|to|search|for)\\b
```

And my replacement text is as follows:

```
$1<span class="gold">$2</span>
```

For a complete code of:

```
var reArray = ['number','numbers'];
var re = new RegExp('(>[^<]*?)\\b('+reArray.join('|')+')\\b', 'gi');
$('body').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(re, '$1<span class="gold">$2</span>'));
});
```